# Flask memory leak. memory profiling

Tags: python, flask, memory-leaks

I built a server through flask.
There are ui, flask server, and python program.

The python program sends 5 Post requests per second and the capacity of the data is 14 mb.
And store it in server memory and release the memory when the data is full to maintain 5.1GB.

However, using ui causes problems. Even in ui, one request per 0.2 seconds is sent to the server to get the value.
In that case, the memory is not maintained, but gradually increased as shown below.

server, python program
[image]
[image]

with ui
[image]

My question is twofold.

1. I can understand that 14mb is allocated to the part receiving the variable with content, but why not allocate 14mb even though it is new data after 5.1GB
2. How to use gc to clear content when each endpoint receives a request (to release memory)

I would appreciate it if you could let me know another way if my question doesn't help me solve the memory leak.